# Is this an acceptable way to autoload html pages with php?

Tags: php

Working on a simple little MVC if you even can call it that. Anyway, I'm using a controller class to autoload html files that matches a $_GET variable. Like go to /?page3 in your browser to load a file called page3.php. Here's the script I've been working on:

```
    public function __construct(){
    // This makes configs and many 
    // global variables available
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.php';

    // Homepage will be included if there is no $_GET
    if($_GET){
        // Check the name of each $_GET in the users URL
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) { 
            /* Check if there is a file
             * named after the input $_GET.
             * Also, make sure there's no hanky panky with the input  */
            if(preg_match ("/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/", $key) && file_exists('html/' . $key . '.php')){
                // Include the file named after the input $_GET
                include 'html/' . $key . '.php';
            }
            // Include homepage if there is no matching file
            else {
                include 'html/home.php';
            }
            // Break loop to stop multiple files from loading
            break;
        }
    }
    // Include homepage if there is no $_GET set
    else {
        include 'html/home.php';
    }
```

Comment: Just FYI, that regex won't match `'page3'` since you're just checking for letters and whitespaces.

Comment: Ah yeah forgot, just used page3 as example. Page names will only have letters. Whitespaces are only included because I don't fully understand regex so used an example

Comment: Please check this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
Because you want to redirect to this page as I assume?

Comment: You don't have a question? You just thought you'd share? :-)

Comment: The thing is that the index file has an autoloader for classes (spl_autoload_register()) so I want to be able to create new files for each page and class. So if I do a full redirect to a html page I will need to reinitialize the autoloader. Thoughts?

Comment: delboy1978uk, the question is whether this is a secure, good practice thing or if I should go another direction to achieve the same result. One guy already said it's bad practice though...

Comment: In an MVC framework you'd not normally do this at all; you'd have a router using `mod_rewrite` which passes all (non-existent) requests to `index.php`. That then parses the `REQUEST_URI` to determine the controller/action that needs to be taken (generally the URIs are mapped to actions in the database)... if you're just pulling in *"views"* from a `GET` var like this, it's not *really* an MVC (as there's no model nor controller).

Answer (score 0):

Short thing:

```
    ob_start();
    include ('html/home.php');
    $fileContent = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
```

It load data from file and catch it, and then you can just echo "$fileContent".

Comment: What is the benefit of this?

Comment: I've used it to load PHP file, and still have working PHP values in this file as far as I remember. It was some time ago I must admit, but it is still working ok.